# How to use sliding window with Kafka Streams DSL?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to find the MAX value for a fixed period (for example, the last 7 days).
In theory, the best way to resolve this task is the sliding window.

My case in the picture:
[image]

I tried to do it with SlidingWindows, but I couldn't write the aggregation function.
I don't understand how to get access to values inside the window.

```
input
   .groupByKey()
   .windowedBy(SlidingWindows.withTimeDifferenceAndGrace(Duration.ofDays(7), Duration.ZERO))
   .reduce(Math::max) // I thinks this is mistake
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't need a sliding window in my case. I need a hopping window:

```
input
                        .groupByKey()
                        .windowedBy(
                                TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(1)).advanceBy(Duration.ofHours(1)))
                        .reduce(Math::max)
.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
```